# Celery and python functools.wrapper

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to create a general wrapper to do the following :

- act as the celery task wrapper
- update the task state/meta **outside** the wrapped function
- update the task state/meta **inside** the wrapped function

**async.py**

```
def my_celery_wrapper(func):
    @celery_app.task(bind=True)
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(task,*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__name__ + " is called")
        task.update_state(state='STARTED')
        func(task,*args, **kwargs)
        task.update_state(state='END')
    return wrapper
```

**foo.py**

```
from async import my_celery_wrapper
import time

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Foo init')
    @my_celery_wrapper
    def bar_async(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'progress':i})
            time.sleep(2)
```

I can't get it to work or detect the task inside the wrapper so my questions are : what is wrong with this code ? And also is it the way to go ?

Comment: it's not altogether clear what you are trying to do. what do you mean "update the meta"?

Comment: I mean update the state/meta of the task like `task.update_state(state='STARTED')` and `task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'progress':i})`. **EDIT**: I updated my question

Comment: this is all very convoluted - and your implementation is even more so - I would recommend trying to simplify things

Comment: For now what I implemented is simpler but requires to manually do the same process each time and follow a 'blueprint'.Using this implementation would be easier (if possible) and not overload the code.